# Runtime complexity of recursion inside loop with memoization

Tags: java, c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, topdown

I would like to know how to determine the time complexity for the following code, using top-down dynamic programming approach with memoization (note that i, k, d can be any integer value):

```
solve(i, k, d) {
    if (k >= d) {
        A[i][k] = 0;
        return 0;
    }

    if (i == 0) {
        A[i][k] = 0;
        return 0;
    }

    if (A[i][k] == null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k + 1; j++) {
            A[i][k] = solve(i - 1, (k + 1 - j), d);
        }
    }

    return A[i][k];
}
```

Comment: Well. You're missing a return statement. But why don't you start with the first branch when `j=0` and trace what happens there -- it terminates after `min(i, d-k)` steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue** :

```
solve(i - 1, (k + 1 - j), d)
```

will give out of bound error when j = 0 as `A` index should go from 0 to K [K being largest index]

---

**ANSWER : The function will give O(n * n) complexity.**

---

**Intuition :**

(it is clear that the worst case is the one where there are no solutions, so I focus on that)

Since the recursive call is made before putting values in the memoization-cache, the last (shortest) suffixes will get cached first. This is because the function is first called with a array of length N, which then calls itself with a array of length N-1, which then .... , with a array of len 0, which is cached and returns, then the array of length 1 is cached and returns, ..., length N is cached and returns.

**Explanation :**

Assuming size of matrix I x K and Considering worst case,

**[Note]** In worst case, Function call will start from right bottom of matrix

`A` initialization happens in two cases :

- `k >= d`
- `i == 0`

**[Note]** In worst case, `k` is always less that `d`.

```
For loop for `(I, K)`
- Recursion call `for (i-1, k:[K to 0])` 
- Update value for `A[i, k]`
```

**[Note]** i = 0 is base case when function initializes `A` and returns 0.